# How to setup Google search to *never* return results for translated keywords?

Tags: google-search, localization

I am interested in - using or studying - several different languages, and I often Google-search a unique word to gain context about its usage or meaning (within the context of the language it belongs to).
One thing that bothers me, is that Google will return first many results that **do not** contain the keyword I entered in the search box. Instead, the results will contain the *English (approximate) translation* of that word.
One way I found to work around this problem is to set the Search Options to return only results in the specific language to which my keyword belongs to. However since I am working with several different languages, it is extremely cumbersome to having to change this setting every time I search for a word in a different language.
An other idea I did not explore would be to create different google accounts with specific search settings for each language. On a desktop computer it might then be easier to switch between search profiles (opening several browsers). However since I am mainly searching foreign words from my mobile phone, this method is very cumbersome as well (it is not smooth to switch between different google accounts).

The ideal solution would be to have a "never translate the searched keyword" option. How can I get Google to support such a feature ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not an *ideal solution* but you could create different shortcuts for Google searches in different languages, then use them (instead of [google.com](https://www.google.com/)) as needed. For example:

- https://www.google.com/webhp?lr=lang_en
- https://www.google.com/webhp?lr=lang_fr
- https://www.google.com/webhp?lr=lang_es

will take you to search pages that return results in English, French or Spanish, respectively.

Similar to `lr=` for the language of the results, there is a `hl=` to choose the language of the google page itself. For example:

- https://www.google.com/webhp?lr=lang_fr&hl=fr

will display the search button in French as `Recherche Google`, and return French-language results if you search for an ambiguous word like `theatre`, or even a purely English one like `Wimbledon`.

More language codes for both results and interface can be found at [Google Web Interface and Search Language Codes](https://sites.google.com/site/tomihasa/google-language-codes).